# Trigger Event on Text box Value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want execute the alert inside the `$("#address").change` function , but that needs to be done only if the the value is changed using the button .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('button').click(function(){
    $("#address").val("hi")
   })
   $("#address").change(function(){
    alert("The text has been changed.");
   });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="address">
<button>Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $("#address").change will trigger if you perform any change in text field. If you want to trigger alert only when button click why you don't use alert inside button click function.

Comment: This is not my original application ! My application deals with changing values dynamically to all the txt fields and i have to trigger event for each! This sample can help with my application ! So i posted this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can trigger `change` event in `click` function:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $("#address").val("hi")
  $("#address").change(); //or $("#address").trigger("change");
});
$("#address").change(function(){
  alert("The text has been changed.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="address" type="text">
<button>Change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the change event like this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $("#address").val("hi")
    $("#address").trigger('change');
  });
  $("#address").change(function(){
    alert("The text has been changed.");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the alert on #address change only when the button is clicked and not when changing the #address value manually:

```
var textChangedHandler = function() {
    alert("The text has been changed.");
};

$('button').click(function(){
    // Attach event handler for 'change' to #address
    $("#address").bind("change", textChangedHandler);

    // Update #address value
    $("#address").val("hi");

    // Trigger 'change'
    $("#address").trigger('change');

    // Remove event handler for 'change' from #address
    $("#address").unbind("change", textChangedHandler);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qcp3e/1/)